# Wildfly10 to Wildfly13 hibernate ogm deployment error

Tags: java, wildfly, hibernate-ogm

Hello I am trying to migrate from WildFly 10 to WildFly 13 and I am facing a problem with hibernate ogm. In wildfly 10 I had hibernate orm 5.1.10 and ogm 5.1.0. 
Wildfly 13 ships with orm 5.1.14. I have an ear application with a depedency to an ejb module where I have the persistence.xml, entities and services for MongoDB.
Tried to deploy the application Wf 13 with ogm 5.1 as wildfly module and 5.1.10 orm as I had it in Wf 10 but no luck. I also upgraded ogm to 5.2.0 and kept orm to 5.10.1 as suggested by the ogm documentation but no luck again. In every case I get the following exception when trying to deploy.

```
WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of subdeployment "swp.drepo.mongodb.jpa.jar" of deployment "swp.trader.core-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.wildfly.jpa.hibernateogm5.HibernateOGMPersistenceProviderAdaptor.beanManagerLifeCycle(Ljavax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.<init>(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deployPersistenceUnitPhaseOne(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:481)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.addPuService(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:273)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.handleJarDeployment(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:166)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    ... 8 more
```

I have tried nearly everything but still not able to find something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully migrated from WildFly 11 -> 12 & 12 -> 13. All used Hibernate OGM with MongoDB.

After getting it working on WildFly 11 & 12 I simply copied all the appropriate module directories across (from 12).

Have you edited the 'module.xml' to point to the correct version of the JAR?

Maybe a typo but WildFly 13.0.0.Final ships with 5.2.14.Final: 
hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar

From what I remember I had problems deploying as the 'search' directory was missing.

From my WildFly 13.0.0.Final installation on macOS.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/13.0.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate

The tree of the directories & files is:

.
├── 4.1
│   ├── jipijapa-hibernate4-1-13.0.0.Final.jar
│   └── module.xml
├── 4.3
│   └── module.xml
├── 5.0
│   └── module.xml
├── 5.2
│   └── module.xml
├── 5.2.14.Final
│   ├── byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar
│   ├── hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar
│   ├── hibernate-envers-5.2.14.Final.jar
│   └── module.xml
├── commons-annotations
│   └── main
│       ├── hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.2.Final.jar
│       └── module.xml
├── envers
│   └── main
│       └── module.xml
├── hql
│   └── 1.5.0.Final
│       ├── antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
│       ├── hibernate-hql-lucene-1.5.0.Final.jar
│       ├── hibernate-hql-parser-1.5.0.Final.jar
│       └── module.xml
├── infinispan
│   ├── 5.2
│   │   └── module.xml
│   ├── 5.2.14.Final
│   │   ├── hibernate-infinispan-5.2.14.Final.jar
│   │   └── module.xml
│   └── main
│       └── module.xml
├── jipijapa-hibernate4-3
│   └── main
│       ├── jipijapa-hibernate4-3-13.0.0.Final.jar
│       └── module.xml
├── jipijapa-hibernate5
│   ├── 5.2
│   │   └── module.xml
│   ├── 5.2.14.Final
│   │   ├── jipijapa-hibernate5-11.0.0.Final.jar
│   │   └── module.xml
│   └── main
│       ├── jipijapa-hibernate5-13.0.0.Final.jar
│       ├── jipijapa-hibernate5-3-13.0.0.Final.jar
│       ├── jipijapa-hibernate5-3-legacy-13.0.0.Final.jar
│       ├── jipijapa-hibernate5-legacy-13.0.0.Final.jar
│       └── module.xml
├── main
│   ├── hibernate-core-5.1.14.Final.jar
│   ├── hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar
│   ├── hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.14.Final.jar
│   ├── hibernate-envers-5.1.14.Final.jar
│   ├── hibernate-envers-5.3.1.Final.jar
│   ├── hibernate-java8-5.1.14.Final.jar
│   └── module.xml
├── ogm
│   ├── 5.3
│   │   ├── hibernate-ogm-core-5.3.0.Final.jar
│   │   └── module.xml
│   ├── infinispan-embedded
│   │   ├── 5.3
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-ogm-infinispan-embedded-5.3.0.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── infinispan-remote
│   │   ├── 5.3
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-ogm-infinispan-remote-5.3.0.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── internal
│   │   └── parboiled
│   │       └── 5.3
│   │           ├── asm-5.2.jar
│   │           ├── asm-analysis-5.2.jar
│   │           ├── asm-tree-5.2.jar
│   │           ├── asm-util-5.2.jar
│   │           ├── module.xml
│   │           ├── parboiled-core-1.1.8.jar
│   │           └── parboiled-java-1.1.8.jar
│   ├── jipijapa
│   │   └── 5.3.0.Final
│   │       ├── hibernate-ogm-jipijapa-5.3.0.Final.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── main
│   │   └── module.xml
│   ├── mongodb
│   │   ├── 5.3
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.3.0.Final.jar
│   │   │   ├── module.xml
│   │   │   └── mongo-java-driver-3.6.3.jar
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── module.xml
│   └── neo4j
│       ├── 5.3
│       │   ├── hibernate-ogm-neo4j-5.3.0.Final.jar
│       │   ├── module.xml
│       │   ├── neo4j-3.3.3.jar
│       │   ├── neo4j-cypher-3.3.3.jar
│       │   ├── neo4j-graph-algo-3.3.3.jar
│       │   ├── neo4j-graph-matching-3.1.6.jar
│       │   ├── neo4j-jmx-3.3.3.jar
│       │   ├── neo4j-kernel-3.3.3.jar
│       │   └── neo4j-udc-3.3.3.jar
│       ├── internal
│       │   └── 5.3.0.Final
│       │       ├── bcpkix-jdk15on-1.53.jar
│       │       ├── bcprov-jdk15on-1.53.jar
│       │       ├── caffeine-2.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── commons-lang3-3.5.jar
│       │       ├── concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar
│       │       ├── lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.5.jar
│       │       ├── lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.5.jar
│       │       ├── lucene-codecs-5.5.5.jar
│       │       ├── lucene-core-5.5.5.jar
│       │       ├── lucene-queryparser-5.5.5.jar
│       │       ├── module.xml
│       │       ├── neo4j-codegen-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-collections-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-common-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-configuration-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3-2.3.12.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1-3.1.6.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.2-3.2.9.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.3-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3-2.3.12.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1-3.1.6.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.2-3.2.9.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.3-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-ir-3.2-3.2.9.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-ir-3.3-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-cypher-logical-plans-3.3-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-graphdb-api-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-index-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-io-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-java-driver-1.5.1.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-logging-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-lucene-index-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-lucene-upgrade-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-primitive-collections-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-resource-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-ssl-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-unsafe-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── neo4j-values-3.3.3.jar
│       │       ├── netty-all-4.1.17.Final.jar
│       │       ├── parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.8.jar
│       │       ├── scala-library-2.11.11.jar
│       │       └── scala-reflect-2.11.11.jar
│       └── main
│           └── module.xml
├── search
│   ├── aws-v4-signer-java
│   │   └── 5.8.2.Final
│   │       ├── aws-v4-signer-java-1.3.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── backend-jms
│   │   ├── 5.10
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-search-backend-jms-5.10.1.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── hibernate-search-backend-jms-5.5.8.Final.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── elasticsearch
│   │   └── 5.8.2.Final
│   │       ├── hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5.8.2.Final.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── elasticsearch-aws
│   │   └── 5.8.2.Final
│   │       ├── hibernate-search-elasticsearch-aws-5.8.2.Final.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── elasticsearch-client
│   │   └── 5.8.2.Final
│   │       ├── elasticsearch-rest-client-5.6.2.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── elasticsearch-gson
│   │   └── 5.8.2.Final
│   │       ├── gson-2.8.2.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── elasticsearch-sniffer
│   │   └── 5.8.2.Final
│   │       ├── elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer-5.6.2.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── engine
│   │   ├── 5.10
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-search-engine-5.10.1.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   ├── 5.8
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   ├── 5.8.2.Final
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-search-engine-5.8.2.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── hibernate-search-engine-5.5.8.Final.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   ├── orm
│   │   ├── 5.10
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-search-orm-5.10.1.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   ├── 5.8
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   ├── 5.8.2.Final
│   │   │   ├── hibernate-search-orm-5.8.2.Final.jar
│   │   │   └── module.xml
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── hibernate-search-orm-5.5.8.Final.jar
│   │       └── module.xml
│   └── serialization-avro
│       ├── 5.10
│       │   ├── hibernate-search-serialization-avro-5.10.1.Final.jar
│       │   └── module.xml
│       └── main
│           ├── hibernate-search-serialization-avro-5.5.8.Final.jar
│           └── module.xml
└── validator
    ├── cdi
    │   └── main
    │       ├── hibernate-validator-cdi-5.3.6.Final.jar
    │       ├── hibernate-validator-cdi-6.0.10.Final.jar
    │       └── module.xml
    └── main
        ├── hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar
        ├── hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar
        └── module.xml

77 directories, 151 files
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and for responding. I managed to deploy it using ogm 5.3 and upgrading orm to 5.2.16